# Linking vertices of graph

Tags: c++, graph

I am very beginner and i've got experience coding linked list. To implement it I must use pointer to the next node:

```
struct Node{ 
int value;
Node* next;
};
```

I understand the idea. But what if to talk about graph? For example, I need to link some node to another points, not just one like in linked list. How can I link node with another points, not just one?

Comment: Look at [adjacency lists](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/graph-representation/a/representing-graphs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a single node can be linked to many nodes, you need to extend your structure to have a list of pointers instead of a single pointer. For example:

```
struct Node{ 
  int value;
  std::list<Node*> links;
```

};

The above example uses std::list. The list is a list of pointers to Node objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of node like this :

```
struct Node{
    int value;
    list<Node> listNode;
};
```

or you can use a list of pointer of node like this :

```
struct Node{
    int value;
    list<Node*> listNode;
};
```

Both can be used, just depend of what you need